# removeEventListener is not removing event on keydown

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am appending an eventlistener whenever my component gets rendered.

```
 mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", e => this.moveIndex(e));
}
```

Even when it is inside of the moveIndex method itself, event listener is not being removed. Here is how I am trying to remove the event.

```
 moveIndex(e) {
    ...
      case 0:
        player.play({
           uri: "https://tv-trtturk.live.trt.com.tr/master.m3u8"
          });
          window.removeEventListener("keydown", e => this.moveIndex(e));
       break;
   ...
}
```

Even when I try to remove this event by button click event, it is not being removed. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: `e => this.moveIndex(e)`  That bit of code actually creates a new function..  So yes, it won't remove it, because it never had it.

Comment: It is actually using keyEvents. Is there any other chance to handle keyEvent according to key codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) requires a listener to be the same:

> The EventTarget.removeEventListener() method removes from the EventTarget an event listener previously registered with EventTarget.addEventListener().

Since `(e => this.moveIndex(e)) !== (e => this.moveIndex(e))`, they are treated as different listeners.

It should be

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", this.moveIndex);
```

and

```
window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.moveIndex);
```

Since `moveIndex` accepts `e` as an argument and Vue binds methods to component instance, `this.moveIndex` can be safely used as a callback.

Comment: It resolved the issue. I have tried the same thing but earlier on but it didn't solve the case at all, which is weird. Nice regards!